# Getting text from textblock defined in style

Tags: c#, silverlight, coding-style

I have a style in my Silverlight 4 app. where I define column names in a grid, is it possible to get these text of the headers from an object with this style? In the code below, what I would like to get is the strings "foo" and "bar", from an object with this style applied.

```
</Grid>
    <Grid
    x:Name="m_Headers"
    Visibility="Visible"
    Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition
            Width="{StaticResource DataColunmWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition
            Width="{StaticResource DataColunmWidth}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock
        Margin="3,0,0,0"
        Text="foo"
        Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBlock
        Margin="3,0,0,0"
        Text="bar"
        Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with pure XAML, you'd have to duplicate the templates or create a custom control which exposes the text values as dependency properties via the template.

The best solution I think is to set up bindings for your Grid headers and fill them using your ViewModel:

```
<Grid
x:Name="m_Headers"
Visibility="Visible"
Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition
        Width="{StaticResource DataColunmWidth}" />
        <ColumnDefinition
        Width="{StaticResource DataColunmWidth}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock
    Margin="3,0,0,0"
    Text="{Binding FooText}"
    Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock
    Margin="3,0,0,0"
    Text="{Binding BarText}"
    Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't think this would help me, as I have a number of different styles that apply to the same object, and what I need to know is which of the columns are actually visible for the given style. If I bind the text as described, I still don't know which ones are visible. Maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: Visibility and text are completely separate issues in this case if I understand you right, so maybe your problem is not the text but how to create and maintain state of your columns.